# OpenCV not detect a circle in the picture

Tags: c++, image, opencv, geometry, detection

I have a problem. I have the code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat src, src_gray;

  /// Read the image
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( !src.data )
    { return -1; }

  /// Convert it to gray
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
  GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

  vector<Vec3f> circles;

  /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
  HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );

  /// Draw the circles detected
  for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
  {
      Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
      int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
      // circle center
      circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
      // circle outline
      circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
   }

  /// Show your results
  namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

This is an example from the website OpenCV ( http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html )

I have the following picture:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vqS9.jpg)

For the image above code OpenCV does not detect the circle - circles.size() is equal 0.

What should I do? What to modify the code?

Comment: As MSalters pointed out, there are certain parameters you should check like: the minimum/maximum radius of circle and the minimum distance you want two circles to be separated from. These modifications are done in `HoughCircles()` of your code snippet. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the default thresholds (200 and 100) for an image with significant deviations from a circle (the solar flames). Not a programming error, just a data/settings issue.